# Spread/ Gather Error: Must supply a symbol or a string as argument

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

I have spread data(df)

```
       Timestamp    area    count   type
2019-08-28 00:30:00 area1     4     A
2019-08-28 00:30:01 area1     1     B
2019-08-28 00:30:02 area1     8     C
2019-08-28 00:30:03 area2     8     A
2019-08-28 00:30:04 area2     1     B
2019-08-28 00:30:04 area2     8     C
2019-08-28 00:30:06 area3     18    A
```

into

```
      Timestamp       area    A    B    C


  2019-08-28 00:30:00 area1   4   NA  NA
  2019-08-28 00:30:01 area1   NA  NA  1
  2019-08-28 00:30:02 area1   NA  8   NA
  2019-08-28 00:30:03 area2   8   NA  NA
  2019-08-28 00:30:04 area2   NA  NA  1
  2019-08-28 00:30:04 area2   NA  8   NA
  2019-08-28 00:30:06 area3   18  NA  NA
```

using code

```
 df %>%
group_by(Timestamp, area) %>%
  spread(type, count)
```

Then, I would like to combine the adjacent rows of the same area so that the table looks like this

```
        Timestamp     area    A    B    C
      <S3: POSIXct>   <chr>  <dbl><dbl><dbl>

  2019-08-28 00:30:00 area1   4   8   1


  2019-08-28 00:30:03 area2   8   8   1


  2019-08-28 00:30:06 area3   18  ... ...
.
.
```

I used code

```
df %>%
  gather(type, count,-area) %>%
  group_by(type) %>%
  mutate(Rank = dense_rank(type), 
         RankOrder = paste0("ord_", row_number())) %>%
  spread(type) %>%
  spread(RankOrder, Rank) %>%
  summarise_all(funs(.[which(!is.na(.))]))
```

but I get the error

> Error in eval_tidy(enquo(var), var_env) : object '' not found`.

**One thing to highlight:**

**The recording of data repeats itself on a daily basis, ie. `area` will repeat for each day. Thus we need to group by day(not datetime, I would like to extract the date only) then group by area I guess? But I am not sure how to do that.**

The final goal is to plot the correlation graph between the various elements in `type`.

Please kindly advise how I could do this. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following approach works by keeping the data in long form until you want to view it in wide form at the end. The basic approach is:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(lubridate)

df <- tribble(
~Timestamp, ~area, ~count, ~type,
"2019-08-28 00:30:00", "area1", 4, "A",
"2019-08-28 00:30:01", "area1", 1, "B",
"2019-08-28 00:30:02", "area1", 8, "C",
"2019-08-28 00:30:03", "area2", 8, "A",
"2019-08-28 00:30:04", "area2", 1, "B",
"2019-08-28 00:30:04", "area2", 8, "C",
"2019-08-28 00:30:06", "area3", 18, "A")

df$Timestamp <- ymd_hms(df$Timestamp)
df$date <- ymd_hms(df$Timestamp) %>% date()
df$area <- factor(df$area)
df$type <- factor(df$type)

df %>%
  group_by(date, area, type) %>%
  summarize(count = sum(count)) %>%
  spread(key = type, value = count)

# # A tibble: 3 x 5
# # Groups:   date, area [3]
# date       area      A     B     C
# <date>     <fct> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 2019-08-28 area1     4     1     8
# 2019-08-28 area2     8     1     8
# 2019-08-28 area3    18    NA    NA
```

Comment: Thank you for the ans. I forgot to mention that data repeat itself on each day. Can we take that into account as well? I've edited the question. Thank you!

Comment: @Harper I've edited my code to group your data by date, area, and type before computing sums. This just drops the time info.

Comment: Thank you very much Gregory, I will give it a try

Answer (score 2):

We could first `spread` the data to wide format and for each `area`, we return `NA` if all the values are `NA` in the column or return the first non-NA value.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  tidyr::spread(type, count) %>%
  group_by(area) %>%
  summarise_all(~if (all(is.na(.))) NA else first(.[!is.na(.)]))

#  area  Timestamp               A     B     C
#  <fct> <dttm>              <int> <int> <int>
#1 area1 2019-08-28 00:30:00     4     1     8
#2 area2 2019-08-28 00:30:03     8     1     8
#3 area3 2019-08-28 00:30:06    18    NA    NA
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(Timestamp = structure(c(1566923400, 1566923401, 
1566923402, 1566923403, 1566923404, 1566923404, 1566923406), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = ""), area = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 3L), .Label = c("area1", "area2", "area3"), class = "factor"), 
count = c(4L, 1L, 8L, 8L, 1L, 8L, 18L), type = structure(c(1L, 
2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L), .Label = c("A", "B", "C"), class = "factor")), 
row.names = c(NA, -7L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Thank you for the ans. I forgot to mention that data repeat itself on each day. Can we take that into account as well? I've edited the question. Thank you!

Comment: @Harper Can you try `df %>%
  mutate(Date = as.Date(Timestamp)) %>%
  tidyr::spread(type, count) %>%
  group_by(area, Date) %>%
  summarise_all(~if (all(is.na(.))) NA else first(.[!is.na(.)]))`

Comment: Hi Ronak I did try that but somehow it left out one year of data(out of 2 years). Do you know the reason by any chance?

Comment: @Harper I am not sure why would that happen. A reproducible example might help.